# R Markdown embedding a function into a simple table

Tags: r, function, report, markdown

I'm new to **R** and I'm really liking the flexibility of **R** Markdown to create reports.

My problem is that I want to use a random number generating function I've created my tables.  I want simple tables to include string headers and the following function:

```
> ran<-function(x){
+     x<-runif(n=1, min=13.5,max=15.5)
+     round(x, digits=2)}.
```

It won't allow me to create a table using this method?

````
```{r}
String   |String   |String
-------|------|------
ran(x)|ran(x)|ran(x)
```
````

My ultimate goal is to create practice worksheets with simple statistics that will be different but within a bounded integer range - so I can ask follow-up questions with some idea of the mean, median etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create and store the data in a hidden chunk and print the data as a table when you need to?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should read up on both how to build working R code and how to code up Rmd files since your function doesn't work and there are a few places in the R Markdown docs that show how to do this:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
ran <- function(x) { 
  runif(n=1, min=13.5, max=15.5) + round(x, digits=2)
}
```

One        |Two          |Three
-----------|-------------|-----------
`r ran(2)` | `r ran(3)`  | `r ran(4)`
`r ran(2)` | `r ran(3)`  | `r ran(4)`
`r ran(2)` | `r ran(3)`  | `r ran(4)`
`r ran(2)` | `r ran(3)`  | `r ran(4)`
````

generates:

[image]

Also, neither SO nor RStudio charges extra for spaces in code blocks. It'd be good to show students good code style while you're layin' down stats tracks.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works great.  I'm afraid I don't know any _good code style_. I'll try Google though and see what I come up with.  Thanks for the tip!

Edit: I just Google R Style Guide and it looks like I've got to learn.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that automates much of the report generation and reduces the amount of code you need to type. For starters, you can turn this into a [parameterized report](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html), which would make it easier to create worksheets using different values of `x`. Here's an example:

In your rmarkdown document you would declare parameters `x` and `n` in the yaml header. `n` is the number of random values you want to produce for each value of `x`. The `x` and `n` values in the yaml header are just the defaults knitr uses if no other values are input when you render the report:

```
---
output: html_document
params: 
  x: !r c(1,5,10)
  n: 10
---
```

Then, in the same rmarkdown document you would have the text and code for your worksheet. You access the parameters `x` and `n` with `params$x` and `params$n`, respectively.

For example, the rest of the rmarkdown document could look like the code below. We put `x` into a list called `x_vals` with named elements, so that the resulting column names in the output will be the names of the list elements. We feed that list to `sapply` to get a column of `n` random values for each value of `x`. The whole `sapply` statement is wrapped in `kable`, which produces a table in rmarkdown format.

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
# Create a named list of the x values that we passed into this document
x_vals = as.list(setNames(params$x, paste0("x=", params$x)))

kable(sapply(x_vals, function(i) round(runif(params$n, 13.5, 15.5) + i, 2)))
```
````

You can now click the "knit" button and it will produce a table using the default parameter values:

[image]

If instead you want to use different values for `x` and/or `n`, open a separate R script file and type the following:

```
rmarkdown::render("Worksheet.Rmd", 
                  params = list(x = c(2,4,6,8), 
                                n = 5),
                  output_file="Worksheet.html")
```

In the code above, the `render` function compiles the rmarkdown document we just created, but with new `x` and `n` values, and saves the output to a file called `Worksheet.html`. (I've assumed that we've saved the rmarkdown document to a file called `Worksheet.Rmd`.) Here's what the output looks like:

[image]

You can also, of course, add parameters for the lower and upper limits of the `runif` function, rather than hard-coding them as 13.5 and 15.5.

If you want to create several worksheets, each with different `x` values, you can put `render` in a loop:

```
df = expand.grid(1:3,5:6,10:11)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  rmarkdown::render("Worksheet.Rmd", 
                    params = list(x=unlist(df[i,]), n=10),
                    output_file=paste0(paste(unlist(df[i,]),collapse="_"),".html"))
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this! I'm getting several error messages specifying that the params$x does not exist.  I can't seem to get anything to work.  Here is the following error message:

    Quitting from lines 18-21 (Test_Parameter_Worksheet.Rmd) 
    Error in paste0("x=", params$x) : object 'params' not found

Comment: Can you add an update to your question with the rmarkdown document and the rendering script that you're using? It's hard to know what's going wrong without seeing the complete code that you're running.

Comment: Hi this is the code I'm running in Mark Down, which gives me what I'm looking for:
```{r echo=FALSE}
eleven.twelve <- function(x){x <-
     runif(n=1, min=11, max=12)
    round(x, digits = 2)
    dollar_format()(x)
 }

Comment: Please paste into your question (not into a comment) the complete rmarkdown document and the render script so that we can see exactly what code you're running and reproduce the error you're getting.